# C++ class declaration after using it

Tags: c++, class, header-files, declaration

I want to create method with an argument which links to `Enemy` which is declared later.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Weapon{
    public:
        int atk_points;
        string name;
        string description;
        void Attack(Entity target){
            
        };
};
class Armor{
    public:
        int hp_points;
        string name;
        string description;
        int block_chance;
};
class Entity{
    public:
        int hp;
        int atk;
        string name;
        vector<Weapon> weapons;
        vector<Armor> armors;
};
```

I tried to search for answers, but nothing I found was helpful.
Here's error log:

```
prog.cpp:9:15: error: ‘Entity’ has not been declared
   void Attack(Entity target){
```

Comment: Note that you should take the argument by reference (or in some case a pointer to it) - copying the `target` is very unlikely to be what you want

Comment: Nice comment by @UnholySheep. May I recommend that you read "Professional C++" by Marc Gregoire or any other, maybe more basic, C++ book - but one which is up to date, i.e. published in the last two years and covering up to C++20.

Comment: You can replace `Entity` with `auto`, even though such code looks ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **problem** is that the compiler doesn't know what `Entity` is at the point where you have used as a parameter type. So you need to tell the compiler that `Entity` is a class type.

There are 2 ways to solve this both of which are given below:

##### Method 1

To **solve** this you need to do 2 things given below:

1. Provide a forward declaration for the class `Entity`.
2. Make the parameter of `Attack` to be a reference type so that we can avoid unnecessary copying the argument and also since we're providing a member function's definition instead of just declaration.

```
class Entity; //this is the forward declaration
class Weapon{
    public:
        int atk_points;
        string name;
        string description;
//------------------------------v------------>target is now an lvalue reference
        void Attack(const Entity& target){
            
        };
};
```

[Working demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2UYQ2ylhIGLYqUTX)

##### Method 2

Another way to solve this is that you can provide just the declaration for the member function `Attack`' inside the class and then provide the definition after the class `Entity`'s definition as shown below:

```
class Entity;   //forward declaration
class Weapon{
    public:
        int atk_points;
        string name;
        string description;
//------------------------------v----------->this time using  reference is optional
        void Attack(const Entity& target);  //this is a declaration
};
//other code here as before


class Entity{
    public:
        int hp;
        int atk;
        string name;
        vector<Weapon> weapons;
        vector<Armor> armors;
};

//implementation after Entity's definition
void Weapon::Attack(const Entity& target)
{
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SWmQ--I1J)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You must declare it earlier. You can, however, define it later, in some circumstances.

To forward declare a class, write this before it is used:

```
class Entity;
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++, such code cannot compile:

```
class A {
    void fooa(B) {}
};

class B {
    void foob(A) {}
};
```

However, such code can be compiled, we can change code in the way:

```
class A { };
class B { };
void fooa(A *, B) {}
void foob(B *, A) {}
```

It works and nothing is recursive.

So, I don't think change to reference is a good idea. The directly way to do that is just to use some trick. For example, change `Entity` to `auto`. Like that: `void Attack(auto target)`.
What's more, with c++20, you can define a concept attackable and make Entity is attackable, I like it much.