# Constructor of struct calling the member function of another class declared as a pointer

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class Cohomology;

struct EMField
{
     std::unique_ptr<Cohomology> coh;
     std::array<DIM> data;

     EMField() {coh -> initializeField(*this);};
}

class Cohomology
{
     private:
        // private members
     public:
        Cohomology(PList params)
        {
             // Constructor of the class
        }

        void initializeField(EMField& field)
        {
             field.coh.reset(this);
             // other methods to initialize field.data using the private members
        }
}
```

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553869/15547591) it is explained that calling a method of an incomplete type is not possible, nor dereferencing the pointer.

In fact, when I try to compile it I get:

```
warning: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Cohomology‘

note: forward declaration of ‘class Cohomology‘
```

**My question is**: How can I delegate the construction of `EMField` to the `Cohomology` class if I cannot use a member of `std::unique_ptr<Cohomology> coh` ?

Comment: You can separate `EMField` to header and implementation. In the header you can use a forward declaration (and avoid #including the header for `Cohomology`) but in the cpp you should #include it and then be able to call `Cohomology`'s methods.

Comment: See method 2 in dupe: [C++ class declaration after using it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72474240/12002570). In particular, just move implementation of `EMField::EMField()` after the classes have been defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the definition of `EMField::EMField()` until after both classes have been defined.

```
class Cohomology;

struct EMField
{
     std::unique_ptr<Cohomology> coh;
     std::array<DIM> data;

     EMField();
};

class Cohomology
{
     private:
        // private members
     public:
        Cohomology(PList params)
        {
             // Constructor of the class
        }

        void initializeField(EMField& field)
        {
             field.coh.reset(this);
             // other methods to initialize field.data using the private members
        }
};

inline EMField::EMField()
{
    coh -> initializeField(*this);
}
```